# Adding up numbers in Word (Office 365) without a table

Tags: microsoft-word

I know we can use AUTOSUM and or SUM() functions to add up numbers in Word but I seem to remember that Word used to have a CALCULATE function that allowed for summing up numbers without a table. Is that still possible in Word for Office 365?
Thank you!

Comment: Are numbers placed one by one or how is their format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean.

In Windows Desktop Word, there is still a ToolsCalculate command that will look for numbers and some operators (at least +-/*) in the current Selection, performs the calculation, copies the result to the clipboard, and displays the result in the Status Bar at the bottom of the Word Window. Numbers separated by paragraph marks, lines, spaces, and pretty much everything else are added up.

It no longer has a keyboard shortcut assigned to it, but you either add one, or add the function to the Quick Access Toolbar. To add it to the toolbar, you can

- click the Customize Quick Access Toolbar dropdown
- click *More Commands...*
- in the dropbox at the top of the left-hand column, select "*Commands Not in the Ribbon*"
- look down the list for "Calculate", select it, and click *Add >>*

Unfortunately one of the default "blob" icons is assigned to the function so it's not easy to see which icon is the "Calculate" icon.

It is also still possible to select a block of numbers that happen to be in a vertical column, even if they are not in a table, but holding down the Alt key while selecting the text with the mouse. (ISTR that this used to be called a "Block Select"). It's not a useful selection technique *except* when you want to use Calculate.

Alternatively, if you have a number of values in specific places in your text, and you want to be able to SUM them, you can use *bookmarks* to name the values, and { = } fields to perform calculations on them. This is not typically a useful approach to calculation except in a MailMerge where the values are inserted from a data source, but...

Let's suppose you have a piece of text like this:

What is the sum of 123.45, 234.56 and 345.67 ? Answer: here

Then you could bookmark 123.45 by selecting it and using Insert->Links->Bookmark to insert a bookmark called "value1". Repeat to name 234.56 as "value2" and 345.67 as "value3"

Then instead of "here", use crl-F9 to insert a pair of the special field code braces {  } and type the following between them:

```
=value1+value2+value3
```

so you have

```
{ =value1+value2+value3 }
```

Select the field and press F9 to update its value. Use Alt-F9 to toggle between "field codes" view and "field results" view. Modify 123.45 to 133.45, select the field and press F9 to recalculate and you should see the modified result. But this is obviously not very robust for a number of reasons - e.g. it is very easy to delete those bookmarks when modifying a value.

Alternatively, you can assign bookmarks using "SET" fields. e.g. you could use this:

```
What is the sum of { SET value1 123.45 }{ value1 }, { SET value2 234.56 }{ value2 } and { SET value3 235.67 }{ value3 } ? Answer: { =value1+value2+value3 }
```

where each pair of { } are the special field code braces, so you need to use ctrl-F9 to insert them. The SET field does not display a result, so you can use { value1 }
or { REF value1 } to display the result.

If you need to use bookmarks to perform calculations, I recommend that you do not use bookmark names that are either the same as field code names (such as SET, REF, AUTHOR etc.) and use bookmark names that do not look as if they could be table cell names, e.g. avoid A1, R1C1 and so on.

Comment: Brilliant! This solved the problem! Thank you!